# Putting numbers in an $\epsilon , N$ proof of uniform convergence of seires

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

I want to show that $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} (5x)^k$$ converges uniformly. That is, it converges uniformly to $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (5x)^k$ for $|x| < a <\frac{1}{5}$. Following the idea of the Weierstrass M-test, consider all $x$ such that $$|x| < a < \frac{1}{5} \Rightarrow |5x| < 5a < 1 $$, so we have

$$ \begin{align}
| \sum_{k=1}^{n} (5x)^k - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (5x)^k| & = |\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} (5x)^k| \\
 &< \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} |(5x)^k| \\
 &< \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} (5a)^k \\
 &< \epsilon
\end{align}
$$

for any given $\epsilon$, since $\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} (5a)^k$ converges for $5a < 1$. So, since the $N$ we get for which $n \geq N \Rightarrow | \sum_{k=1}^{n} (5x)^k - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (5x)^k| < \epsilon$, is independent of $x$, since $\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} (5a)^k$ is independent of $x$, thus our series converges uniformly. So far so good. (Please correct me if I have done something wrong up until now.)

Now, because it's not really clear to me exactly what's happening here I want to put numbers into this proof and say for $\epsilon = 0.01$ find the $N$ value. And then for a couple values of $x$ verify that indeed $| \sum_{k=1}^{n} (5x)^k - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (5x)^k| < 0.01$. But it's at that point that I don't know how to proceed.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit 1:** Changed the range of conversion from $|x| < \frac{1}{5}$ to $|x| < a <\frac{1}{5}$

Comment: I believe that it doesn’t converge uniformly on $|x|<1/5$ It does converge uniformly on $|x|<a$ for any $a<1/5$

Comment: Thanks, I believe you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Note that $$\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} (5x)^k={(5x)^{n+1}\over 1-5x}$$when $|x|<{1\over 5}$.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. It gave me the insight to figure it out. But in the more general case that instead of $\sum_{k = n+1}^{\infty} (5a)^k $ you have $\sum_{k = n+1}^{\infty} M_k $, and you don't know the number $M_k$ converges to, but you do know that it converges, how do you proceed?

Comment: You're welcome. The most general case may be unsolvable and very complicated but one good way is to find an upper bound that leads you to an inequality relation between $x,\delta,\epsilon$ and is often easier to solve or crack than the original one. For example$$\sum{1\over x^k+1}<\sum{1\over x^k}$$

Comment: Wait, how could it be unsolvable? The Weierstrass test says that you can always find such an N.

Comment: I think I misled you. I meant, the exact value of the series may be unknown.

Comment: You mean the exact number $M_k$ converges to?

Comment: Yes. That is what I meant. Mostly in hard cases we do not know what exactly $M_k(x)$ tends to, so we need approximates and bounds.